# Transferring incoming data to the model in Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper, mapper

I want to do something like this at Automapper.

I want to transfer the list from the database to the following model.

```
public class GetListModel
{
    public int RowNumber { get; set; } = 0;
    public object Records { get; set; }
}
```

Namely;
Data from the database

```
Name, Surname, Phone, Email, RowNumber
```

I want to take the Row Number from this list and write it to "RowNumber" in "GetListModel".

And. I want to write the other data to "Records" as a list.

Consequently it should look like this.

```
GetListModel{
            int RowNumber = 20,
            object Records = List<User> [
                                            {Name=Ali1,Surname=Kara,Email=mail@mail.mail,Phone=05553333333},
                                            {Name=Ali2,Surname=Kara,Email=mail@mail.mail,Phone=05553333333},
                                            {Name=Ali3,Surname=Kara,Email=mail@mail.mail,Phone=05553333333},
                                            {Name=Ali4,Surname=Kara,Email=mail@mail.mail,Phone=05553333333},
                                            {Name=Ali5,Surname=Kara,Email=mail@mail.mail,Phone=05553333333},
                                            {Name=Ali6,Surname=Kara,Email=mail@mail.mail,Phone=05553333333}
                                            ...
                                        ]
                                        }
```

Please help me.

Normally I do this to transfer the list directly to the model.

```
return new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { cfg.CreateMap<sp_Panel_Get_Orders_Result, OrderModels.For.Panel.ListModel.Order>(); })
.CreateMapper().Map<List<sp_Panel_Get_Orders_Result>, List<OrderModels.For.Panel.ListModel.Order>>(Get);
```

Comment: is there a reason why you use object instead of IEnumerable<T> for Records?

Comment: I'm using a common model for GetList. I take the data with JsonResult and transfer it to the page. I'm trying your solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

@Gleb

I guess couldn't. We disagree.

I need to get the total value from the first record.

**Records.Count()** is not.

It should be **Records.FirsOrDefault().RowNumber**.

*Sampling;*

There are a total of 26 records in the database.

I filter and paging.

Incoming record 8 pieces.

The total number of pages is displayed in the incoming records. (RowNumber)

**Incoming data model in this way;**

```
sp_Panel_Get_Products_Result: [
        { RowNumber: 26, ID: 9, Name: "Ali1", Surname: "Kara", Email: "a@a.a",  Phone: "05553" },
        { RowNumber: 26, ID: 10, Name: "Ali2", Surname: "Kara", Email: "a@a.a",  Phone: "05553" },
        { RowNumber: 26, ID: 11, Name: "Ali3", Surname: "Kara", Email: "a@a.a",  Phone: "05553" },
        { RowNumber: 26, ID: 12, Name: "Ali4", Surname: "Kara", Email: "a@a.a",  Phone: "05553" },
        { RowNumber: 26, ID: 13, Name: "Ali5", Surname: "Kara", Email: "a@a.a",  Phone: "05553" },
        { RowNumber: 26, ID: 14, Name: "Ali6", Surname: "Kara", Email: "a@a.a",  Phone: "05553" },
        { RowNumber: 26, ID: 15, Name: "Ali7", Surname: "Kara", Email: "a@a.a",  Phone: "05553" },
        { RowNumber: 26, ID: 16, Name: "Ali8", Surname: "Kara", Email: "a@a.a",  Phone: "05553" }
]
```

**I want to map it this way;**

```
    GetModels: {
      ListModel: {
        RowNumber_int: 26,
        IEnumerable_T: [
          { ID: 9, Name: "Ali1", Surname: "Kara", Email: "a@a.a",  Phone: "05553" },
          { ID: 10, Name: "Ali2", Surname: "Kara", Email: "a@a.a",  Phone: "05553" },
          { ID: 11, Name: "Ali3", Surname: "Kara", Email: "a@a.a",  Phone: "05553" },
          { ID: 12, Name: "Ali4", Surname: "Kara", Email: "a@a.a",  Phone: "05553" },
          { ID: 13, Name: "Ali5", Surname: "Kara", Email: "a@a.a",  Phone: "05553" },
          { ID: 14, Name: "Ali6", Surname: "Kara", Email: "a@a.a",  Phone: "05553" },
          { ID: 15, Name: "Ali7", Surname: "Kara", Email: "a@a.a",  Phone: "05553" },
          { ID: 16, Name: "Ali8", Surname: "Kara", Email: "a@a.a",  Phone: "05553" }
        ]
      }
    }
```

I want to take the RowNumber value from the first record and print it to the RowNumber property.

And.

I want to map the records to IEnumerable .

:)

*(Sorry, I'm using google translate for English.)*